# Utilizar objeto entre as funções JavaScript - PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, apache-cordova

Estou criando em `onDeviceReady` um objeto para criar a conexão com o banco de dados SQLite da aplicação. O mesmo está sendo criado da seguinte forma:

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
        this.db = null;
    },
    ...
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name:'4routes'});
        ...
```

Porém, existe um método chamado `insertDailyServices` que é responsável por armazenar as informações no banco e a mesma está retornando erro.

```
insertDailyServices: function(service) {
    app.db.transaction(function(tx){
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO file_servico (id_servico,id_os,id_fornecedor,id_motorista,id_veiculo,origem,destino,inicio,termino,created_at) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', 
        [service.id_servico,service.id_file,service.id_fornecedor,service.id_motorista,service.id_veiculo,service.origem,service.destino,service.inicio,service.termino,moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')],
        function(tx,res){
            $('#listServicos').append('Serviço de N&deg; '+service.id_servico+' registrado localmente.<br>');
        });
    });
}
```

Erro apresentado

```
08-31 01:54:03.100: E/Web Console(31269): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'transaction' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js:136
```

Chamada no arquivo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
    app.listOpenServices();
</script>
```

Como resolver esse problema??? Só preciso passar o `app.db` pra ser lido de qualquer método  dentro do arquivo.

Comment: Parece que você está chamando a função `inserDailyservices` antes de ter chamado `initialize` e `onDeviceReady`.

Comment: Pior q não, ela é chamada depois... No arquivo html existe um `app.initialize()` e depois um `app.inserDailyServices()`

Comment: Tem certeza que é depois? UM erro muito comum em Javascript é misturar código assíncrono (callbacks) com código síncrono. O resultado é que algumas coisas rodam antes do esperado.

Comment: Atualizei no final como o método está sendo chamado no arquivo html.

Comment: E onde está a chamada do `insertDailyServices`? O que o @hugomg disse está correto. O "depois" a que ele se refere é no tempo, não na posição no código-fonte. Precisa ser depois do `onDeviceReady` (ou seja, lá de dentro, ou dentro de alguma outra função chamada no `onDeviceReady`). Isso supondo que o `onDeviceReady` esteja devidamente "armado" pelo `bindEvents`.

Comment: Sim, o `onDeviceReady` está dentro do bindEvents e o método `insertDailyServices` está sendo chamado dentro do `onDeviceReady`, pra ser mais exato é a última linhad e código dentro do `onDeviceReady`, que no caso é a chamada para o meu método.

Answer (score 1):

O `initialize` faz com que `app.db` fique nulo. Você poderia fazer isso no `initialize`:

```
this.db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name:'4routes'});
```

Parece que com esse `SQLitePlugin` você precisa chamar o `openDatabase` dentro do `onDeviceReady`, se você chamar dessa forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
    app.listOpenServices();
</script>
```

Pode dar problema. Remova isso do HTML e deixe da seguinte forma no javascript:

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
        this.db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name:'4routes'});;
    },
    ...
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        this.initialize();
        this.listOpenServices();
        ...
```

Comment: Vou testar e já dou uma resposta.

Comment: Agora ele mudou a resposta: `09-02 12:48:50.364: I/Web Console(24544): SQLitePlugin openargs: {"name":"4routes"} at file:///android_asset/www/plugins/com.brodysoft.sqlitePlugin/www/SQLitePlugin.js:39``

Comment: Eu acho que você está chamando o openDatabase desse plugin cedo demais, veja a resposta atualizada.